# Some usage of brackets in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have found an example on the net, that is not natural for me, concerning brackets usage :

```
does = is = { true => 'Yes', false => 'No' }
does[10 == 50]                       # => "No"
is[10 > 5]                           # => "Yes"
```

Can anybody explain this ?

Comment: While those are valid Ruby examples, I wouldn't generally write that way because, as you can tell, they are very terse and tend to obscure what is happening. Yes, they're "deep-magic" and are taking advantage of interesting boolean tricks, but they're out of place in Ruby coding because Ruby code should be more readable. In Perl or C you'd see similar things written, where being boolean-studly is often picked over being readable/maintainable by people who think it makes the code run faster.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### First line

```
does = is = { true => 'Yes', false => 'No' }
```

This line initializes two hashes in which the value of `true` is `"Yes"` and the value of `false` is `"No"`. Note that they are actually the same object in memory with two references, so it is the same of

```
is = { true => 'Yes', false => 'No' }
does = is
```

and not the same of

```
is = { true => 'Yes', false => 'No' }
does =  { true => 'Yes', false => 'No' }
```

### Second line

```
does[10 == 50] # => "No"
```

Evaluate `10 == 50`, which is false, and use as the hash key, returning `"No"`.

### Third line

```
is[10 > 5]  # => "Yes"
```

Same thing, evaluate `10 > 5` which turns out to be true, and using true as the hash key it returns `"Yes"`

Note that this is not a new command on ruby, the squares are just accessing the hash value.

Comment: This is why everyone should learn functional programming, makes this kind of thing super obvious, even if you don't know the language.

Answer (score 1):

`{ true => 'Yes', false => 'No' }` is a Hash, so `does[ 10 == 50 ] == does[false]`, which is 'No'. The same for the other example.

Answer (score 0):

`5<10` is a boolean expression so this will return `true` or `false`.

`does` and `is` are dictionaries (in Ruby-speak Hashes). The keys for those dictionaries are true and false.
The values are "Yes" and "No".

So, `is[ 10 > 5 ]` = `is[true]` = `"Yes"`

Comment: This is a Ruby question. Ruby doesn't have dictionaries, it has Hashes, so, don't say "`does` and `is` are dictionaries" because they're not. In *OTHER* languages they might be, but you need to use the right vernacular when discussing Ruby, Perl and other languages that have "hashes", not "dictionaries". Failing to do that will make your answers appear foreign and look like you don't know the language at all.

Comment: I disagree. The word "hash" as a term for a collection of keys mapped to values is utter nonsense. A hash is the value output by a hash function. The hash value is a (significant) implementation detail, but an ill-suited term to describe data structure as a whole. Kitchens have ovens, but we don't use oven to as a word to describe a room intended for cooking. Nor would we refer to a database as a join.

Ruby needs to change it's vernacular to match common programming lingo - not the other way around.

Comment: Plus, in Ruby 1.9+, it's even impossible to implement `Hash` using a hash table. You have to at least add a linked list or use some other data structure.

Answer (score -1):

The first line is a chained assignment. I don't really see the point. Basically you are creating a hash and assigning a reference to `is` and then assigning the reference of `is` to `does`. So you have two local variables pointing to the same hash object.

The second and third lines are expressions that evalute to values which are then used for lookup. 10 is not equal to 50, so this evalutes to false. False is a key in the hash with a value of "no". 10 is bigger than 5, so it evalutes to true which also happens to be a key with a value of "Yes".

Comment: "The first line is a chained assignment. I don't really see the point." Making `is` and `does` point to the same thing is similar to providing an alias that gives a method an alternate name. It's syntactic sugar, used to help the flow of the statements. Sometimes it makes more sense grammatically to say `is`, sometimes `does` makes more sense.